# Move Parity Wallet Large Blockchain files to another drive (Windows)

Tags: parity-wallet

Running Parity filled up my C Drive, as I also had a Myst wallet there as well. I don't remember if the install program asked for the place to store the files.

If I move these files to another drive, how do I reconfigure Parity to tell it where the files are now? I checked the settings tab, and don't see any options. I checked in c:\Program Files\Ethcore\Parity and only see 3 .exe's and an .ico files.

By running WinDirStats (to find out why my disk was full), I found the huge files at c:\users\myname\Local\Parity\Ethereum\chains\ethereum\db (then a few more folders deeper).

Comment: Access Denied during MKLINK command ... am i the only one with this issue ? no and there a Solution cause syntax is incorrect. mklink has the following syntax : mklink [options] <Link> <Target>
Target is the file/folder that exists, and Link is the created one that links to the target. so the command should be: mklink /D "E:\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup" "C:\Users\odellt1\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directory junction using *MKLINK*.

First rename the folder or copy it to D:\Parity (assuming you wand the data to be in the D: drive.  XXXX below refers to you user name).

```
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Parity
```

Then use mklink:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Parity D:\Parity
```

Then just copy everything into D:\Parity if you already have files in the original (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Parity) location.

Comment: Had to return to this issue today to get it working.  See also: https://superuser.com/questions/597551/mklink-error-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exists.  The command I had to run was: C:\WINDOWS\system32>mklink /J "%LOCALAPPDATA%\parity" "e:\ParityWallet" and the response was 
Junction created for C:\Users\MyUserXxxx\AppData\Local\parity <<===>> e:\ParityWallet

Answer (score 1):

The files in question are Parity's database files.  The location of the database directory can be assigned via settings in Parity's configuration file.  On Windows, this file is located at `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\config.toml`.  The [Parity Config Generator](https://paritytech.github.io/parity-config-generator) provides a web UI for exploring the available settings and generating complete configuration files.

On Windows, one can relocate Parity's database directory from `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Parity\Ethereum\chains` (the default location) to `D:\ProgramData\Parity\Ethereum\chains` by moving the directory and assigning the following setting:

```
[parity]
db_path = "D:\\ProgramData\\Parity\\Ethereum\\chains"
```

This can be done with the assistance of the Parity Config Generator as follows:

1. Stop Parity.

   1. Right-click the **Parity** icon in the Windows system tray.  Choose **Exit**.
2. Configure Parity to use the new location for its database directory.

   1. Navigate to the [Parity Config Generator](https://paritytech.github.io/parity-config-generator).
   2. For **Mode**, choose **Advanced Configuration**.
   3. Expand the **Parity** section.
   4. For **Database Path**, enter `D:\ProgramData\Parity\Ethereum\chains`.
   5. In the **`config.toml`** preview panel, click the [image: Download Config File] button.  Save the file as `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\config.toml`.
3. Start Parity Ethereum.

You may want to consider also adjusting some other Parity settings that control how and where Parity stores various files:

- **Parity** ➧ **Base Path**
- **Parity** ➧ **Light**
- **Footprint** ➧ **DB Compaction Profile**

Source: [Parity Ethereum Documentation ➧ Configuring Parity ➧ Config File](https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity#config-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it directly in the command prompt:

```
parity --db-path="E:\New_db_folder_name"
```

P.S. - make sure you navigated to the folder where your parity.exe is located and/or you added it's location to your PATH.  For me, when installing parity, I changed the regular path, i.e. *"C:\Program Files(x86)\Parity"* to somewhere on my E: drive

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be using a configuration file, and changing the blockchain location
https://wiki.parity.io/Configuring-Parity

Comment: That will not _move_ the existing data, but _recreate_ the required data

Comment: neither will mklink from the previous answer